# Slow performance firedac with SQL Server under Delphi Tokyo update 1

Tags: sql-server, delphi, azure-sql-database, ado, firedac

Using a simple query that returns 20.000 rows only takes 0.5 milliseconds with ADO, but using firedac it takes 30 seconds.

This is the code used for FireDac and ADO test:

```
procedure TForm18.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: DWORD;
begin
  i := GetTickCount;

  Query.DisableControls;
  Query.Active := false; // simple SQL SELECT * FROM TABLE
  Query.Active := true;
  Query.EnableControls;
  Caption :=  IntToStr(GetTickCount - i) + ' - ' + IntToStr(Query.RecordCount);
end;
```

Regards

[image: Test FireDac vs ADO]

Comment: Does it help when you comment out the call to Query.RecordCount?

Comment: Is your connection already connected? Connection.Connected can be false and running a query will first open the connection. That could take some time depending on your setup.

Comment: In addition to what @UweRaabe asked, does the FD operation speed up if you move the call to `RecordCount` above `EnableControls`?

Comment: What's the purpose of that dataset object? Why do you need to fetch 20k tuples to the client? Are you sure that ADO didn't fetch only a few tuples to the client and FireDAC all?

Comment: // Query.RecordCount has not effect

Comment: Connection is connected before open SQL

Comment: In both cases are linked to TDBGrid as you can see in image below.

Comment: You seem to be doing this in both your timing cases, but if you include `EnableControls` in your timings, you might include the time it takes for data-bound controls to react to changes of the dataset. TDataSet e.g. will either send a `deDataSetChange` or `deLayoutChange` when `EnableControls` is called. Could it be that ADO and FireDAC DataSets will behave differently there? One causing TDBGrid to load data, the other not?

Comment: Test is basically the same..., because I have testing it with linked DBGrid and without

Comment: Would you mind timing query execution and how long `EnableControls` take seperately? And output the rows the grid has? Something like this: `uses
  System.Diagnostics;

procedure TForm18.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AStopWatchQuery, AStopWatchGrid: TStopWatch;
begin
  AStopWatchQuery.StartNew;
  Query.DisableControls;
  Query.Active := false; // simple SQL SELECT * FROM TABLE
  Query.Active := true;
  AStopWatchQuery.Stop;

  AStopWatchGrid.StartNew;
  Query.EnableControls;
  AStopWatchGrid.Stop;
end;`

Comment: Profile the code if you know there's a bottleneck. And once again, are you sure that ADO fetched all the tuples? And is not e.g. in asynchronous mode? I mean, can those two components compete with their configurations? And what is the configuration of your FireDAC dataset object? Could you include these information into your question, please?

Comment: @Victoria, is linked to DBGrid, and in both cases retrieves all data in the grid. Connections is synchronous, I have no checked especial properties, basically drop components to the form.

Comment: After various test I detect the cause: MARS. With MARS disabled the performance is similar in ADO and FireDac

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting the ExtendedMetadata to False for better performance. Try using also the RecordCount property with the number of records expected and you may see better results.

That SELECT statement does not use any indexes so a full scan of the database is occurring. Try to compare performance with a query that filter results and make use of indexes use indexes instead.

You can alos use ADMonitor to see how the application interacts with the database as explained [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Tracing_and_Monitoring.html).

Finally, I have read about slow performance when FireDac uses ODBC and also when FireDac reads BLOB data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is asking why two different Delphi component libraries produces different results,  What you say may be true, but does not seem to be relevant to this difference.

Comment: ExtendedMetadata is false